# Firebase Request simplification and error fixing

Tags: json, firebase, api, express, http

I have a bunch of forms that input data into my firebase database using a express API and cloud functions.

***I have one main issue - I'm getting a error on trying to test my API when inputting the form data.***

*The secondary issue is more, is there a cleaner way to take the inputted form data to the firebase than how I am currently doing it.*

This is the code to create a new workflow (which is the data outputed from the forms)

```
(this is the required code from the route file)

const {getAllWorkflows,
    postOneWorkflow} = require('./handlers/workflow');
// Workflow Routes

app.get('/Workflows', getAllWorkflows);
app.post('/Workflow', postOneWorkflow);
```

And this is the request code from a handler file

```
exports.postOneWorkflow = (req, res) => {
  const newWorkflow = {
    completed: req.body.completed,
    currentStep: req.body.currentStep,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    Reason: req.body.Reason,
    breach: req.body.breach,
    cauInd: req.body.cauInd,
    cauOth: req.body.cauOth,
    cauWea: req.body.cauWea,
    claimEoT: req.body.claimEoT,
    dateAware: req.body.dateAware,
    dateEoTClaim: req.body.dateEoTClaim,
    daysClaimed: req.body.daysClaimed,
    dec: req.body.dec,
    delayRespon: req.body.delayRespon,
    descB: req.body.descB,
    descCau: req.body.descCau,
    descExt: req.body.descExt,
    event: req.body.event,
    eviCause: req.body.eviCause,
    eviExtent: req.body.eviExtent,
    ifGranDay: req.body.ifGranDay,
    notice: req.body.notice,
    proMitPro: req.body.proMitPro,
    proResPro: req.body.proResPro,
    recWri: req.body.recWri,
    stepsMit: req.body.stepsMit,
    stepsPre: req.body.stepsPre

  };

  db.collection("Workflow")
    .add(newWorkflow)
    .then(doc => {
      const resWorkflow = newWorkflow;
      resWorkflow.WorkflowId = doc.id;
      res.json(resWorkflow);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

I'm currently receiving an error of

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 10
```

when inputting json using postman to the workflow post route,

```
{
        completed: "False", 
        currentStep: 1,
        claimEoT: "True",
        event: "True", 
        notice: "True", 
        recWri: "True", 
        dateEotClaim: "",  
        dateAware: "",  
        eviCause: "",    
        descCau : "",
        eviExtent : "True",
        descExt : "",
        daysClaimed : 5,
        delayRespon : "True",
        proResPro : 1,
        stepsPre : "True",
        proPrePro : 1,
        stepsMit: "True",
        proMitPro : 10 ,
        breach : "True",
        descB : "describe",
        cauInd : "True",
        cauWea : "True",
        cauOth : "True",
        dec : "True",
        ifGranDay : 5,
        Reason : "I AM THE SENATE"
      }
```

Not 100% sure why as it seems like my formatting is fine?

With creating the query - I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this other than writing an ungodly amount of code for the queries.

The point is I need to be able to query the different collections and edit them, but I feel like a query that just took in what it was told, and sent it through to this database, without having to specify the specific "completed", or "Reason",would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your postman JSON is invalid. The keys are also supposed to be enclosed in quotes.

```
{
 "completed": "False", 
 "currentStep": 1,
 ...
}
```

2. You can just create the newWorkflow object from req.body!

```js
  const newWorkflow = req.body;
  newWorkflow.createdAt = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: Damn - ritalin is a helluva drug - thanks stupid mistake, appreciate your suggestion!!!